# Mysql Count with DAYOFWEEK AND BETWEEN not working together

Tags: mysql, between, dayofweek

I am trying to count a value where I get the count from the weekday and from the first 3 months of the year.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(count_LP) AS down1 
FROM
  `splittest` 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(DATE) = 2 
  AND (
    dato BETWEEN 2014-01-01 
    AND 2014-04-01
  )
```

It stops working when I add the BETWEEN.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify dates you have to quote them like `'2014-01-01'`

```
SELECT 
  SUM(count_LP) AS down1 
FROM
  `splittest` 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(DATE) = 2 
  AND (
    dato BETWEEN '2014-01-01' 
    AND '2014-04-01'
  )
```